# Pandas updates not reflecting in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas

---

### Edit:

According to

```
print(pd.__version__)
```

I am using pandas version

> 0.20.3

I tried updating pandas using

```
!pip3 install pandas
```

Although I have the latest version , according to this:

> Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.1.3)
> Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (2020.1)
> Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (1.19.2)
> Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
> Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.15.0

when I try to see the version of pandas I am using after the update, I still seem to be using the old version.

```
print(pd.__version__)
```

> 0.20.3

I have tried restarting my mac and the anaconda navigator, but I still seem to be using the earlier version of pandas and not the updated one.
Why is the updated/latest version of pandas not reflecting in jupyter notebook?

---

### Original question:

I am trying to read a json file in chunks. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json

for gm_chunk in pd.read_json('filename.json', lines=True, chunksize=100):
    df= gm_chunk
    df['column'].str.lower()
    df.to_csv('filename1.csv', mode='a', header=False, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8'
```

I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: read_json() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chunksize'

Comment: Looks like your pandas version is simply too ancient: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.21.0.html?highlight=chunksize#new-keywords

Comment: I updated my answer. Try that!

Comment: @FrozenAra.. I'd tried conda update pandas earlier as well.... nothing had worked. I just uninstalled and reinstalled everything and it's working now. I don't know what exactly was broken though..Thanks to all of you for your help.

Comment: Of course. No problem!

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_json.html?highlight=read_json#pandas.read_json) `read_json()` doesnt accept a chunksize parameter.
On the website the arguments are listed as follows:
`pandas.read_json(path_or_buf=None, orient=None, typ='frame', dtype=True, convert_axes=True, convert_dates=True, keep_default_dates=True, numpy=False, precise_float=False, date_unit=None, encoding=None, lines=False`

I dont know why the code ran before. **Edit:** Its possible that your code run
previously because you used a newer version.
**Edit 2:** Try this `conda update pandas` 
You probably have to update your anaconda package separately like that.

You need to update your pandas version.

Comment: just to note: chunksize is available in later versions of pandas, so perhaps the questioner was previously using a more modern version of pandas.

Comment: Yeah thats probably the case here.